# Display PHP content with .text method in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using WordPress and the [Polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/)-plugin.

I'm trying to set the text contents of three `li` elements through jQuery. This is not a problem. It becomes a problem though, when I need to display the text with PHP.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".dot:nth-child(1)").text("<?php echo pll_e('String 1'); ?>");
    $(".dot:nth-child(2)").text("String 2");
    $(".dot:nth-child(3)").text("String 3");
});
```

Is there an alternative or am I doing something wrong? Maybe it's not even possible.

Comment: This will work as long as your are in a `.php` file. What is the output of `echo pll_e('String 1');`? Do you get any errors in your javascript console?

Comment: @JonathanCrowe you're absolutely right! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @JonathanCrowe; as long as you're doing it in a `.php` file it'll work. I simply placed it in my `footer.php` file inside `<script>`-tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $(".dot:nth-child(1)").text("<?php echo pll_e('Om Os'); ?>");
        $(".dot:nth-child(2)").text("<?php echo pll_e('OES-analyse'); ?>");
        $(".dot:nth-child(3)").text("<?php echo pll_e('Malingsinspektion'); ?>");
        $(".dot:nth-child(4)").text("<?php echo pll_e('Metallurgi'); ?>");
        $(".dot:nth-child(5)").text("<?php echo pll_e('PMI test'); ?>");
        $(".dot:nth-child(6)").text("<?php echo pll_e('Hårdhedsmåling'); ?>");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Presumably your JavaScript is not in a file with a `.php` extension that is executed by PHP. Or perhaps `pll_e('String 1');` returns a string with a `"` (double quote) in it.

To solve either problem you could do the following (this is quick and dirty)

```
// in a file called thejsfile.js
function foo(obj) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        // you could consider running this as a loop
        // $('.dot').each(function () { /* ... */ });
        $(".dot:nth-child(1)").text(obj.str1);
        $(".dot:nth-child(2)").text(obj.str2);
        $(".dot:nth-child(3)").text(obj.str3);
    });
}
```

In a file that is executed by PHP and the output is sent as an HTTP response.

```
<?php 
$array = array(
    'str1' => pll_e('String 1'),
    'str2' => pll_e('String 2'),
    'str3' => pll_e('String 3'),
);
$jsInitObj = json_encode($array);
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="thejsfile.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(obj) {
    foo(obj);
}(<?php echo $jsInitObj; ?>));
</script>
```

Another alternative would be to load the value of `pll_e('String 1');` via an AJAX request.

**EDIT**: Updated answer to accommodate the question in the comments below.

Comment: Excellent reply, @robbmj! What would be the cleanest way of writing the PHP function with multiple strings (e.g. `str1`, `str2`, `str3`) all with different strings?

Comment: Thanks @FrederickAndersen. I have updated my answer to accommodate the above question. Please have a look. I hope this helps you out.

Comment: `<?php $array = ['str1' => pll_e('String 1'), 'str2' => pll_e('String 2'), 'str3' => pll_e('String 3')]; $jsInitObj = json_encode($array); ?>` results in an error: `Parse error : syntax error, unexpected '[' in (...)`

Comment: @FrederickAndersen You are using an older version of PHP. I will update the answer so that it doesn't give you the parse error. the `[]` notation for arrays was added in `PHP 5.4`

Comment: You're correct, however it now returns `NULL` as the text value; still no errors.

Comment: I've updated my question with the code I'm using. Please have a look.

Comment: I will have a look shortly.

Comment: Well, I just placed the code I originally used in the `footer.php` and it worked. Thanks for your time, though!